# Creating a class and Method for a coin flip

Tags: java, class, methods

I am doing a practice problem that deals with the flipping of a coin. I understand every other step, but I am confused at how to first setup the method and class. I am confused with the variables that they have given me. The question aks,

Define a class Coin with 2 instance data, a string face, which can be “heads” or “tails” and an int value that represents the monetary value of the coin. The following method should be included in the class:
- a default constructor
- a constructor that takes 2 parameters to initialize instance data

So my question to everyone is how would I go about creating this?

This is what I have so far:

```
public class Coin
{
    private int Value;
    private String Face;

    public Coin(int a)
    {
        Value = a;
        Face = "heads";
    }

    public Coin(int b, String faceTails)
    {
        Value = b;
        Face = "tails";
    }
```

Comment: You're missing the default constructor -- one that takes ***no*** parameters at all. You'll have to give your value and face default values in this constructor. Note that Java variable names should begin with a lower-case letter, so value and face, not Value and Face. Next, your 2 parameter constructor isn't using the second parameter but rather is simply ignoring it.

Comment: Alright, so I need to setup a default constructor hosting the same name as the class name, then in that constructor in the body, define heads or tails? and thanks for the lower-case letter tip, no idea why I used capital letters. Also, for the initializing of the instance data using 2 parameters, what do you mean by ignoring it?

Comment: What I mean is where do you use the faceTails parameter to set a class field similar to what you do with the b parameter?

Comment: I think I was just getting confused with what the question was asking to be honest and originally put an extra parameter thinking that it was for something that was really not needed. I am pretty sure that I have a better understanding of it now than I did last night. Thanks again for the explanation though!

Answer (score 1):

From your requirements:

Define a class Coin with 2 instance data, a string face, which can be “heads” or “tails” and an int value that represents the monetary value of the coin. The following method should be included in the class:

- a default constructor:

An empty bean constructor needs to be defined in Java if there is a constructor that takes an argument, like so:

```
public Coin(){...}
```

- a constructor that takes 2 parameters to initialize instance data

You have this defined properly, but you may not need the constructor with 1 argument.

```
public Coin(int b, String face)
{
    this.value = b;
    this.face = face;
}
```

You may also want to add some getters for the field values so you can access the values from outside the class.